# Error installing contextify- node-gyp rebuild failed

Tags: node.js, topojson, node-gyp, contextify

**Edit**

I upgraded node and ran "npm install -g contextify" It looks like it installed fine (no errors), but typing in "which contextify" returns nothing. Message while installing contextify:

```
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/contextify
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/contextify
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/bindings
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/bindings

  > contextify@0.1.6 install /usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/contextify
  > node-gyp rebuild

CXX(target) Release/obj.target/contextify/src/contextify.o
SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/contextify.node
SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/contextify.node: Finished
contextify@0.1.6 /usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/contextify
└── bindings@1.1.1
```

**Original**

I'm having a problem installing contextify with npm:

```
npm install -g contextify
```

and get the following error messages:

```
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/contextify
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/contextify
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/bindings
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/bindings

> contextify@0.1.6 install /usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/contextify
> node-gyp rebuild

  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/contextify/src/contextify.o
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/contextify.node
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/contextify.node: Finished
/usr/local/Cellar/node/0.10.1/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/node-gyp-bin/node-gyp: line 2: 73593 Segmentation fault: 11  node "`dirname "$0"`/../../node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "$@"

npm ERR! contextify@0.1.6 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! `sh "-c" "node-gyp rebuild"` failed with 139
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the contextify@0.1.6 install script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the contextify package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls contextify
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! System Darwin 13.0.0
npm ERR! command "/usr/local/Cellar/node/0.10.1/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "contextify"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/projects/
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.1
npm ERR! npm -v 1.2.15
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
```

Anyone know what's going on here? I read that it may have something to do wit my PYTHON PATH, but I'm not sure how it should look.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Can you add more of the output? It should have said what the error was above this section. Are you on Mavericks?

Comment: Sure, just added it in. I'm on Mavericks too.

Comment: Looks like this may be [a bug in Node](https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/6427), have you tried with more recent versions? `v0.10.1` is from almost 10 months ago.

Comment: Updated node and the thread

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Original problem

> Segmentation fault: 11  node "`dirname "$0"`

This appears to be a bug in V8 exposed by compiling with Clang. It's been fixed in more recent versions of Node, so you'll need to update. The github issue is tracked [here](https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/6427)

#### Edit problem

There is no `contextify` command-line program that you can run, so `which contextify` has nothing to find. The `contextify` module is meant to be used within `node` by using `require('contextify')` to load the module.

Based on how you've described this, it seems like you may be conflating two things. Modules installed with `npm install -g` are installed globally and accessible to all node applications, but that does not mean that they will expose a script that can be executed on the command line. `-g` only controls the installation path of the module.

Whether a module has a command-line script you can run depends on whether the module's `package.json` defines a set of `bin` commands, e.g. [jshint](https://github.com/jshint/jshint/blob/af845907d5772d090ab0c3ed99f20491bbbca5f0/package.json#L22-24). When you install with `-g`, the scripts listed are symlinked along with `node` so they are accessible via your `PATH`. When installed without `-g`, bin scripts are installed into `node_modules/.bin` and you would have to add that directory to your `PATH` for scripts to work.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand what you're saying. That brings up one more question. Do I have to change anything in my PATH when I install packages globally?

Comment: Not usually. Generally Node installs itself into a standard application directory, which will already be in your path.

Comment: Looks like it doesn't support node 4.x yet: https://github.com/brianmcd/contextify/issues/180

Answer (score 11):

I had the same problem with `node-gyp rebuild`. The solution was install **g++**:

```
apt-get -y install g++
```

Answer (score -1):

There is no such thing as `contextify` binary. There is `contextify.node` binary in `/usr/lib/node_modules/contextify/build/Release/` (when installed globally in my ubuntu 12.04).

Just use the module in your node program by using `require('contextify')` and it should work.

```
var Contextify = require('contextify');
var sandbox = Contextify(); // returns an empty contextified object.
sandbox.run('var x = 3;');
console.log(sandbox.x); // prints 3
sandbox.dispose();
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're saying. I don't have /contextify in /usr/lib/local/node_modules.