# can't npm install bcrypt in my docker image

Tags: node.js, debian, docker, sails.js, bcrypt

I'm trying to get my `Sails.js` app up and running using the standard `node` Docker image but the build is failing when it tries to `npm install bcrypt`.

```
> bcrypt@0.8.0 install /myapp/node_modules/bcrypt
> node-gyp rebuild

gyp WARN install got an error, rolling back install
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: node-v0.10.33.tar.gz local checksum 822ba41f2d77b704ab63e244dfef7431b31893c19bfe3bf228c06b6aff063ed5 not match remote 75dc26c33144e6d0dc91cb0d68aaf0570ed0a7e4b0c35f3a7a726b500edd081e
gyp ERR! stack     at deref (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/install.js:299:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/install.js:340:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:117:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at _stream_readable.js:943:16
gyp ERR! stack     at process._tickCallback (node.js:419:13)
gyp ERR! System Linux 3.16.1-tinycore64
gyp ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /pos/node_modules/bcrypt
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.33
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v1.0.2
gyp ERR! not ok
```

Alternatively sometimes it simply fails as follows:

```
> bcrypt@0.8.0 install /myapp/node_modules/bcrypt
> node-gyp rebuild

Killed
```

And sometimes it just hangs indefinitely at

```
> bcrypt@0.8.0 install /pos/node_modules/bcrypt
> node-gyp rebuild
```

### My `Dockerfile` looks like:

```
FROM node:0.10.33

#  copy the source files into the image
ADD . /myapp

# Define working directory.
WORKDIR /myapp

# Install node-gyp as global and ensure it's all clean and tide
RUN npm install -g node-gyp && \
    node-gyp clean && \
    npm cache clean

# Install project dependencies
RUN npm install

# Expose sails port (still in development mind you)
EXPOSE 1337

# Define default command.
CMD ["node app"]
```

### Things I've tried

- [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22405844/917187) in another Stackoverflow thread suggested I should also `RUN apt-get -y install g++` but adding that to my `Dockerfile` made no difference and it just reports that `g++ is already the newest version.`
- [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20895568/917187) suggested I ensure `openssl` is installed so I added `RUN apt-get install -y openssl` that that also reported `openssl is already the newest version`.
- I've also tried `RUN apt-get install -y build-essential` but that too reports that it's already the latest version.

I've seen suggestions that Node needs to be installed as a `legacy` version, which is something the standard Node image ought to be responsible for, if necessary I believe, so I've also reported this as [an issue with the docker-library/node](https://github.com/docker-library/node/issues/28) project.

In the meantime, what else ought I try?

Comment: The core of your issue is the `node-v0.10.33.tar.gz local checksum ...  not match remote ...` error. The correct SHA is pulled from https://nodejs.org/dist/v0.10.33/SHASUMS256.txt, so something is causing your downloaded `.tar.gz` to be corrupted. Maybe try to download the tar from https://nodejs.org/dist/v0.10.33/ manually and calculate the sha256 and see if it matches then, to at least localize the problem.

Comment: Are you behind any proxy or firewall ?

Comment: It looks like node has been updated to 0.10.33_1 this morning so I'll see if that helps.  No - not behind a proxy or firewall

Comment: I'm trying your `Dockerfile` with a simple `package.json` that has `bcrypt` 0.8.0 as a dependency and it builds just fine. My Docker node image ID is `387247331d9c`. Can you confirm your Docker image base ID and maybe supply a `package.json`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone whose advice in the comments and answers steered me to my conclusion.

The issue was either some sort of corruption within my `docker` install, or some sort of incompatibility between `dvm` and `fig`, but I solved this problem as follows

```
dvm down
brew remove fig
brew remove dvm
brew remove docker
brew cleanup --force -s
rm -rf ~/VirtualBox VMs/boot2docker-vm
brew install docker
brew install boot2docker
boot2docker init
boot2docker up
echo export DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1 > ~/.bash_profile
echo export DOCKER_CERT_PATH=~/.boot2docker/certs/boot2docker-vm > ~/.bash_profile
echo export DOCKER_HOST=tcp://$(boot2docker ip 2>/dev/null):2375 > ~/.bash_profile
export DOCKER_HOST=tcp://$(boot2docker ip 2>/dev/null):2375
brew install fig
fig build web
```

and voila - it worked.

The trick really seemed to be that I had a couple of conflicting bits of crud in my original `boot2docker-vm` from having it installed originally via the installer and then later by `homebrew` and `boot2docker` colliding somehow with `dvm`.  By wiping it all back to bare metal and rebuilding from scratch it all worked nicely.